# Splitting a large CSV file with the command line

Tags: macos, bash, unix, split

I know OS X supports the Linux-like `split` command.

I have a huge file `file.csv`.

When I run

```
split -l 1000 file.csv new_
```

I get created one file `new_aa`, but this file is the same as `file.csv`. It is not split.

When I run file file.csv, I get `ASCII text, with CR line terminators`. BTW, running `wc -l` command shows that `file.csv` has 0 lines.

Comment: How many lines does `file.txt` have? If just ran `seq 10000 > a` (10K lines) and then `split -l 1000 a new_` and I got 10 files `new_a{a..j}`.

Comment: if your huge file comes from windows world, you may want to check the line breaks. what `wc -l` reports on your file?

Comment: @Kent it is a `CSV` file

Comment: The format is not relevant on UNIX systems. Just provide the `wc -l` output from this file. You can also say `cat -vet file.csv | less` to see if some weird characters are confusing everything.

Comment: @fedorqui indeed I tried `wc -l` command and it outputs `0` how can it be ?

Comment: difficult to know. Try to run `dos2unix file.csv` to convert it to a proper UNIX mode. Just to be sure, create a backup of the file before, since the file gets modified in place.

Comment: @Kent it seems that there is `0` line. DO I need to add some `\n` at the end of each line ?

Comment: @Newben you can either follow fedorqui's advice (dos2unix) or use `-t` option of `split`

Comment: @Newben Can you confirm there are any linebreaks actually in the file?

Comment: @123 when I run `file file.csv`, I get `ASCII text, with CR line terminators`

Comment: @Newben Do dos2unix then like suggested above.

Comment: @Kent there are no `-t` option at least on `OSX`. Btw, I tried `dos2unix` and I still get a `0` lined file

Comment: Then try to do `mac2unix file.csv`.

Comment: thanks @fedorqui . But why down voting ? bwt, could you set it as a response ?

Comment: I suspect the downvote is due to the lack of details in the actual question. One has to read all the comments to discover the relevant details

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your command is just fine:

```
split -l 1000 file.csv new_
```

However, it seems that you have some encoding problems. When you say `file file.csv` you get

> ASCII text, with CR line terminators

So what you need is to port this file from MAC to UNIX. And this can be done with either of these:

```
mac2unix file.csv
dos2unix -c mac file.csv
```

Comment: This *might* also work to convert the line endings: `sed -i.bak 's/\r/\n/g' file.csv`

Comment: Note that this will convert the file in place irreversibly, so maybe make a copy first :)